# PigServer script execution

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

I have a java code that generates pig script. I am wondering if there is option to execute that script directly within the java code. I found there is a option to embed pig script execution inside java code using [PigServer](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/api/org/apache/pig/PigServer.html) class.

The problem is that I'm using AvroStorage to store the results and the class contains method `Store()` that apparently uses file storage.

Is there any way how to execute my pig script using AvroStorage inside JAVA using PigServer class?

Its generic code from their DOC, they use pigServer.store("D", "myoutput"); but instead of the file i need to call AvroStorage.

```
public class WordCount {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      PigServer pigServer = new PigServer();

      try {
         pigServer.registerJar("/mylocation/tokenize.jar");
         runMyQuery(pigServer, "myinput.txt";
        } 
      catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }

   public static void runMyQuery(PigServer pigServer, String inputFile) throws IOException {        
       pigServer.registerQuery("A = load '" + inputFile + "' using TextLoader();");
       pigServer.registerQuery("B = foreach A generate flatten(tokenize($0));");
       pigServer.registerQuery("C = group B by $1;");
       pigServer.registerQuery("D = foreach C generate flatten(group), COUNT(B.$0);");

       pigServer.store("D", "myoutput");
   }
}
```

Comment: Where is this code that you have?

Comment: what code do you mean? I cant find as part of the PigServer class API any usable method for that usecase.

Comment: *I have a java code that generates pig script* - please add that code to your question so we know what you are talking about

Comment: Ok, please check it now.

Comment: Okay. Can you not use `registerQuery` like `"STORE D INTO "myoutput" USING AvroStorage()"`?

Comment: then who will execute all the commands.... . store method kick off execution of the all commands... i guess.

Comment: You will `pigServer.executeBatch()`